# I am getting a proper output but i want to slice only to the first 5 values please tell me how do i do the slicing for the same operation

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, output, slice

I have written this code to find the max values. The code is working perfectly, but I want to slice it to the first five values and display only first 5. How do I slice it? Please help me!! 
Thanks in advance

```
Student=[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, I, j, k, l, m, n, O, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z]                                                                          
marks=[45, 78,12,14,48,43,47,98,35,80]                         
student_marks= dict(zip(student, marks))                       

    for i in student_marks:                                                    
        max_key= max( student_marks, key= student_marks.get)                                                               
        student_marks.pop(max_key)                                   
        all_values= student_marks.values()                      
        max_values= max(all_values)                               
        print(max_key, max_values)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please share your code. One way could be `print(my_list[:5])`

Comment: I have used the above code. I am not able to slice

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code that sort the list by decreasing order, then print only the 5 first elements of the list.

```
max_values=[45, 78, 12, 14, 48, 43, 47, 98, 35, 80]                        
max_values.sort(reverse=True)  # Sort the list by deacreasing order
print(max_values[:5])          # Print only the 5 first values of the list
```

EDIT:
I take for hypothesis you have a list of with student names and marks.
First, use `list.sort` function to sort the data the way you need, Secondly, use `print(list_of_marks[:5])` to only take the first 5 values:

```
list_of_marks = [['a', 45], ['b', 78], ['c', 12], ['d', 14], ['e', 48],
                 ['f', 43], ['g', 47], ['h', 98], ['I', 35], ['j', 80]]
list_of_marks.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])
print(list_of_marks[:5])
```

output:

```
[['h', 98], ['j', 80], ['b', 78], ['e', 48], ['g', 47]]
```

Comment: I want to print the corresponding student as well!

Comment: I've edited my post to try to give an answer. You need to post all your data and expected values if you need more help.